# Angular ui-router upgrading to 1.0.x . 'resolve' errors

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

hi I am trying to upgrade from 0.2.8 to 1.0.0-beta.1 on ui-router and run into this error in any state that uses the 'resolve' property. 
For example,  I get **'Invalid resolve value: "q"** errors from the state below

```
state('myState', {
                url: '/myState?filter',
                component: 'myComponent',
                resolve: ['$q', '$ocLazyLoad', function ($q, $ocLazyLoad) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer()
                      .....
                }]
            })
```

Can someone point me in the right direction for using 'resolve' in ui-router 1.0 ? The docs pretty much suck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

resolve is supposed (and has always supposed) to be an object, with functions as values. See [the documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider#methods_state):

> An optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller. If any of these dependencies are promises, the router will wait for them all to be resolved before the controller is instantiated. [...]

Comment: thank you for the link. that helped. it's not clear in the docs that i was reading.